# Two forms - one submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, api, recurly

I have TWO forms on my website.

Is it possible when I submit one of these, it will take form data from a particular field in the other form?

I am using the Recurly system with PHP.

Comment: Maybe you can add `hidden` input fields on your forms, and copy the data onchange or onclick, to ensure you get the results of both forms.

Comment: Yes it can be done with javascript. You would have to construct two requests with handpicked fields and then send them.

Comment: @Lan That's a really good point. I may update the session data with each onChange and then carry this through Recurly.

Comment: Copying data between fields is fairly trivial with JS, but why would you not just include that particular field in the first form in the first place?

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn, unfortunately, I'm at the mercy of the 3rd party software, so I can't create custom fields :'( I think I'll go with Lan's suggestion and update a session variable after each change to that form.

Comment: Remember that if you send 2 or more forms via `document.forms["form1"].submit();`, each request will be aborted except for the last one. So, another solution is send the forms via AJAX calls.

Comment: Good idea. I think I'll use AJAX calls to a PHP script to create/update the session. Then use the session data once the form has been submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own function.

```
function submit (){
   document.getElementById("firstform").submit();
   document.getElementById("secondform").submit();
}
```

You can then make a button that calls this function.

If this doesn't work, try again using ajax.
[Example](http://plungjan.name/test/duosubmit.html)

Comment: That looks the perfect job! I'll away and test and report back later. Thank you.

Comment: UM, if they actually perform a post to the current page that is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript.

For example:

```
var request =false;

function submit()
{
    var yourobject = document.getElementById("yourobject").value;

    data = "yourobject" + "=" + encodeURIComponent(yourobject);

    request.open("POST", "yourpage.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(data);
}
```

And the input:

```
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="Submit" />
```